# How do I bypass the CORS policy when retrieving data from URLs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv, cors

I am working on a tool that will read URLs in an uploaded CSV file and search each text content of the URLs and count the total words of the page and the total occurrences of "saas" or "software". The download button is supposed to create a new CSV file with the existing URLs in column 1, the total words in column 2 and the total occurrences in column 3. The URLs are to be sorted according to most occurrences to least and if the URLs contain the keywords "saas" or "software" it should be highlighted in green, otherwise in red.

This is what I coded:

```
type hereconst myFileInput = document.getElementById("myFileInput"); // get the input element
let urls = []; // initialize an empty array to store the URLs from the CSV file
let arrayNum = []; // initialize an empty array to store the word counts and "saas"/"software" occurrences

// function to extract URLs from the CSV file
function extractUrlsFromCsv(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader(); // initialize a FileReader to read the uploaded CSV file
  reader.onload = function() {
    const lines = reader.result.split("\n"); // split the CSV file into lines
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      urls.push(lines[i].split(",")[0]); // extract the first column (URLs) from each line and add it to the urls array
    }
    processUrls(); // call the processUrls function to start processing the URLs
  };
  reader.readAsText(file); // read the uploaded file as text
}

// function to process the URLs
function processUrls() {
  if (urls.length === 0) {
    createCsv(); // if there are no more URLs to process, call the createCsv function
    return;
  }
  const url = urls.shift(); // get the first URL from the urls array and remove it from the array
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      const words = text.split(" "); // split the text into words
      const wordCount = words.length; // get the total number of words
      const saasOrSoftwareCount = words.filter(word => word.toLowerCase() === "saas" || word.toLowerCase() === "software").length; // get the total number of "saas" or "software" occurrences
      arrayNum.push([url, wordCount, saasOrSoftwareCount]); // add the URL, word count, and "saas"/"software" count to the arrayNum array
      processUrls(); // call the processUrls function again to process the next URL
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(`Error fetching ${url}: ${error}`); // log any errors
      processUrls(); // call the processUrls function again to process the next URL
    });
}

// function to create the CSV file
function createCsv() {
  arrayNum.sort((a, b) => b[2] - a[2]); // sort the arrayNum array in descending order of "saas"/"software" occurrences
  let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
  csvContent += "URL,Total Word Count,\"saas\"/\"software\" Count\n"; // add the column headers to the CSV content
  arrayNum.forEach(row => {
    const url = row[0];
    const wordCount = row[1];
    const saasOrSoftwareCount = row[2];
    const rowContent = `${url},${wordCount},${saasOrSoftwareCount}\n`; // create a row of CSV content for each URL
    csvContent += rowContent;
  });
  const encodedCsvContent = encodeURI(csvContent); // encode the CSV content as a URI
  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.setAttribute("href", encodedCsvContent);
  downloadLink.setAttribute("download", "urls.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click(); // create a link with the encoded CSV content and click on it to trigger the download
}

myFileInput.addEventListener("change", event => {
  const file = event.target.files[0]; // get the uploaded
```

Comment: By making the requests on the server.

Comment: Bypassing CORS via javascript would defeat the purpose of it existing in the first place. You will want to use server side code to scrape those URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. At least not on your frontend code. Either set appropriate CORS rules on the server, or (if the first is not possible) have a backend “proxy” the requests.